# Using Vim command to insert text to multiple lines

Tags: vim, mapping

I know in visual block mode, by `<S-i>` (`I`) one can insert in multiple selected lines, however I want to achieve the same effect by a function, let's say I have a functions which can tell the three sub-visual modes (`visual-character`, `visual-line`, `visual-block`) as follows,

```
function! VisualMappingSpace()
    let m = visualmode()
    if m ==# 'v'
        echo 'character-wise visual'
    elseif m == 'V'
        echo 'line-wise visual'
    elseif m == "\<C-V>"
        echo 'block-wise visual'
    endif
endfunction
```

I've tried as follows but it doesn't work. I want to insert soemthing to the lines I select when I hit `<space>` in `visual-block` mode.

```
function! VisualMappingSpace()
    let m = visualmode()
    if m ==# 'v'
        exec "normal y"
    elseif m == 'V'
        exec "normal y"
    elseif m == "\<C-V>"
        let g:block_insert_content = input("")
        exec "normal I ".g:block_insert_content
    endif
endfunction   
vnoremap <silent> <Space> :call VisualMappingSpace()<CR>
```

Comment: `exec "normal y"` should be `normal y`. Anyway, what do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: Actually what I expected is in `visual-character` and `visual-line` mode when I hit `<space>` I can copy the selected lines to the default register, and in `visual-block` mode when I hit `<space>` I can insert something to the lines I selected, just like what I hit `I` in `visual-block` mode do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A visual-mode mapping that enters command-line mode via `:` will have the visual range (`'<,'>`) automatically inserted. With `:call`, that means that **your function is invoked once per selected line**. You should have noticed via the repeated queries.

To avoid this, insert `<C-u>` into your mapping; it clears the range.

Second problem: When you insert the queried text, **you need to re-create the selection** (your mapping left visual mode for command-line mode, remember?) via `gv`; then, `I` will work:

```
function! VisualMappingSpace()
    let m = visualmode()
    if m ==# 'v'
        exec "normal y"
    elseif m == 'V'
        exec "normal y"
    elseif m == "\<C-V>"
        let g:block_insert_content = input("")
        exec "normal gvI ".g:block_insert_content
    endif
endfunction   
vnoremap <silent> <Space> :<C-u>call VisualMappingSpace()<CR>
```

Also note that there is an additional space character before your queried text; I'm not sure you want that: `gvI ".`